# Easy version control + version comparison for TeX

Tags: open-source, ubuntu, git

What would you suggest for this situation.

Person studies mathematics and uses Xubuntu on his home computer. He needs to write his thesis such that he can see different versions easily. Someone suggested git but is it hard if one has no background on programming? Is there some easy to use gui where one sees different versions? I would not like to pay anything on the software.

Comment: The person needs to visually see the difference between their thesis now and the thesis one month ago, for instance? Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: I mean that you can see differences as text but I would like to have some easy GUI where I can see different versions of files.

Comment: I am trying to understand your need. Is there a particular reason would you need to compare with a file from one month ago? Or are you writing two very similar theses?

Comment: Will you need to perform such comparisons several times per day, or is it a one-time need?

Comment: Ok. I wrote my thesis and once my supervisor wrote than my writing would go to the wrong direction. I managed to return to the point where I started to do wrong things by downloading the previous version from my email and save that version back to my hard disk. I started to write different versions by saving them by names with timestamp, like `thesisv13jan2019.tex`. But now I have big number of similar files. I just want to some easy way to modify different versions. I think I need comparisons once in a few days.

Comment: I realize I might have misunderstood something: Do you want the version comparison to show differences in the rendered result (with images fonts etc), or just the TeX source code? (the latter is much easier)

Comment: IMHO one can learn git easily under the given conditions: local use only, no server required, only one person working on the project, no branches

Answer (score 1):

You can try Git + (git)latexdiff, as described in [the SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188780/git-latex-workflow) about Git+LaTeX workflow.
One-person Git is easy to use. Git is popular so you will not have any problems with GUI or additional software.

Alternatively, you can try [Gitless](https://gitless.com/).